# Node.js and sockets.io; Emitting not working

Tags: node.js, sockets

I've this code:

Server (Using http.Server):

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.emit("prompt");
    socket.on("retval", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://ip:port');
    socket.on('prompt', function (data) {
        var username=prompt("Enter username");
        var password=prompt("Enter password");
        socket.emit("retval", { name: username, pass: password });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not getting the prompt when I open the page, I'm getting it only when I terminate the node process (CTRL + C).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code it's difficult to diagnose your problem, but here's a working example:

```
var http = require("http");
var io;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  var html = "<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>"
           + "<script>"
           + "  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');"
           + "  socket.on('prompt', function (data) {"
           + "    var username=prompt('Enter username');"
           + "    var password=prompt('Enter password');"
           + "    socket.emit('retval', { name: username, pass: password });"
           + "  });"
           + "</script>";
  res.end(html);
});

io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("connection");
  socket.emit("prompt");
  socket.on("retval", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

server.listen(8080);

console.log("Server listening on port 8080");
```

When you start this as a node instance you should see this output in your terminal:

```
$ node server.js
  info - socket.io started
Server listening on port 8080
```

Load `http://localhost:8080/` in your browser and the username prompt should appear.

Comment: There was a delay, now fixed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350630/nodejs-with-socket-io-delay-emitting-data?rq=1